# MSBuild behaves different on several machines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

So I have a solution with 6 projects and one Webproject in it. Some referenced dll's in the webproject (ie Aspose.dll and Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll) **do not** have copy local set to true in the project file, but when I open the solution on my local machine and look at the properties of the reference have set copy local to true.

We have several build machines, on some MSBuild consumes the dll and outputs it into the bin directory and on another is treats it as copy local = false.

When I open the solution on the build machine that is failing, the copy local to true setting is now removed and set to false, causing the build to fail. On all other machines it shows up as true.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this?

Comment: Ok, I found the cause of this behavior. Basically it depends on the dll's being registered in the GAC, as explained very clearly [here](http://bronumski.blogspot.com/2009/06/project-reference-fun-and-games.html)
The solution suggested is to set the copy local to true for all required dll's. That's a lot of configuration for referenced project that contain a lot of other dll's.

Comment: you need to submit your comment above - and the url as the answer cos this helped me - and fix my problem. Even to the extent of adding, and then toggling.

Answer (score 1):

One other tip is to make sure you don't reference things from the current directory in msbuild files - i.e. don't do "../../Xyz" but instead ground them against a 'known' directory like "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../../Xyz" - that way when they're running in a variety of contexts (build agents) they *should* still do the right thing.

(Other well known properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx )